# Camera process running in the background?

Tags: linux, process, kali-linux, camera, socks

While trying to fix another problem in `netstat -anp`, I noticed something like this:

```
unix 2   [ ACC ]   STREAM  LISTENING   8421  417/arc_camera_serv   /run/camera/camera.sock
```

Yesterday when I found it, it was listening on 9441. So I put a new rule in iptables to drop all for that port while I figure out what’s going on, but now it seems to have moved to another port.

Basically what I'm asking is....are there people watching me eat? Or does the camera always run listening like that on a port? I've never seen that unless you wanted an external connection.

Lastly, I found this process as well

```
unix 3   [ ]       STREAM  CONNECTED   15094   1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
```

I'm running Kali simply because all my other computers are breaking and Debian and even Ubuntu are breaking. Why is it bringing up Ubuntu on a Kali install?

Comment: “Ouch!  Ouch!  This frying pan is too hot!  I think I’ll get some relief by jumping into that nice, welcoming fire instead.”  If you can’t get Debian and Ubuntu to work, switching to Kali is *not* the solution.

Comment: lol I've had them running. It's just the hardware they ran on got destroyed including an 8-core i7 and 1080ti (threw my ps4 from 20 stories and now my productivity is way up) But, now I'm stuck on a Chromebook also known as failbook. All distros break within 10 minutes except Kali, I know you are supposed to virtualize it but I have no money or choice. BTW I'm pretty proficient with Kali, as far as a Security+ and CEH will take you. I'm not a reverse engineer.